# Symfony2 Authentication (Login) without Doctrine?

Tags: php, symfony, authentication

i'm new @ symfony and absolutely new at doctrine. On the symfony page is an tutorial about build an login process in sf2. And i love it, BUT i cant work with doctrine and i dont wanna work with it (there are many thinks that dont work with doctrine... - e.g. enum´s, etc).

How i create an login controller, firewall setup, etc.. is explained very good. BUT! i would like to create it without doctrine... i have an existing database, and i love plain sql. :-)

How can i use plain sql in an UserInterface... that will work with the build-in login from sf2?

Thx a lot...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is to plug in your own UserProvider:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html

In place of the Doctrine 2 Object Relational Manager (ORM) you might consider using the Doctrine 2 Database Access Layer(DBAL).  This is a thin sql layer built on top of PDO.  Has some helper routines for building sql.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/dbal.html

Of course you can just use PDO directly:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/pdo_session_storage.html

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution I propose on Symfony 3.0.

As I implement an **existing postgresql database and I want to re-use a lot of an already existing PHP code, ORM was not a fit in my case** (too much timecost to do the reverse engineering). Hence I have been actively searching how to use **Symfony without ORM**. (I did implement DBAL because what I wrote for PDO works with it... so far ... with some minor fixes).

Let's start:
The important concept I needed to understand were taken from this page: 
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_provider.html + all the things about the security.yml file.

About the security file, it took me a while to understand that the **node 'providers' had only two native option:'entity' or 'memory'**. And with **'entity'**, one was **bound to work with ORM**. So I figured out that I **needed to develop my own provider that would work with regular PDO**.

Here some part of my code to give you an idea on how I finally made it work, you'll find below the following files:

- security.yml (There are probably still some room for improvement here, as I haven't dig too much the 'firewall' part organization);
- CustomUsersProvider.php : The class implementing the interface
  UserProviderInterface (The class PdoCustom and its method getUser() are my own PDO cooking to retrieve the user from my DB);
- services.yml: The service giving access to the class CustomUsersProvider and hence providing access to the 'provider' in the security file (if I unsderstood it correctly), I pass the DBAL database config as an argument in the service so it can be used in the instance of my object CustomUsersProvider;
- CustomUsers.php : a class acting as an entity of my table
  'custom_users', to work with the PDO::FETCH_CLASS type of PDO fetch; it implements Symfony interfaces: UserInterface and EquatableInterface;
- You still have to implement the Symfony Controller SecurityController (find it here: http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/security.html) and its route to /login and Twig file.
- You'll probably notice when reading the code that $email is used as $username;

### [projectname]\app\config\security.yml

```
encoders:
    CustomBundle\Entity\CustomUsers:
       algorithm: [enter an encoding algorithm, eg: MD5, sha512, etc.]

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_NAME2: ROLE_NAME1
    ROLE_NAME3: ROLE_NAME2

providers:
    custom_users_provider:
        id: custom_users_provider

firewalls:
    main_login:
        pattern: ^/login$
        anonymous: ~
    main:
      pattern: ^/
      anonymous: true
      provider: custom_users_provider
      form_login:
         check_path: /login_check
         login_path: /login
         provider: custom_users_provider
         username_parameter: email
         password_parameter: password

       logout: true

access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/secured_for_role_name, role: ROLE_NAME }
```

### [projectname]\CustomBundle\Security\CustomUsersProvider.php

```
<?php
namespace CustomBundle\Security;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UsernameNotFoundException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UnsupportedUserException;

use CustomBundle\DependencyInjection\PdoCustom;
use CustomBundle\Entity\CustomUsers;


class CustomUsersProvider implements UserProviderInterface
{
    private $dbalConnection;
    private $logger;

    public function __construct($dbalConnection){
        $this->dbalConnection = $dbalConnection;

        ////////////////EASTER EGG//////////////////////////
        $this->logger = $GLOBALS['kernel']->getContainer()->get('logger');
        $logger->info('EASTER EGG: YOU CAN ADD LOG THAT CAN BE FOUND UNDER [projectname]\var\logs\dev.log WHEN LAUNCHING THRU app_dev.php, WICH COULD BE USEFUL TOO');
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    }


    public function loadUserByUsername($username)
    {
        $PdoCustom = new PdoCustom($this->dbalConnection);
        $userData = $PdoCustom->getUser($username);


        if ($userData) {

            $password = $userData->password;
            $salt = null;
            $role = $userData->role;

            $resToReturn = new CustomUsers();
            $resToReturn->setCharact($username, $password, $role);
            return $resToReturn;
        }

        throw new UsernameNotFoundException(
            sprintf('Username "%s" does not exist.', $username)
        );
    }

    public function refreshUser(UserInterface $user)
    {
        if (!$user instanceof CustomUsers) {
            throw new UnsupportedUserException(
                sprintf('Instances of "%s" are not supported.', get_class($user))
            );
        }
        return $this->loadUserByUsername($user->getUsername());
    }

    public function supportsClass($class)
    {
        return $class === 'CustomBundle\Entity\CustomUsers';
    }
}
?>
```

### [projectname]\src\CustomBundle\Ressources\config\services.yml

```
custom_bundle.custom_users_provider.class : CustomBundle\Security\CustomUsersProvider

custom_users_provider:
                 class: %custom_bundle.custom_users_provider.class%
                 arguments: ["@doctrine.dbal.default_connection"]
```

### [projectname]\CustomBundle\Entity\CustomUsers.php

```
  <?php
namespace CustomBundle\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\EquatableInterface;

class CustomUsers implements UserInterface, EquatableInterface {

public $email;
public $password;
public $role;

public function __construct(){
}

public function setCharact($email,$password,$role){
    $this->email = $email;
    $this->password = $password;
    $this->status = $status;

}


public function getRoles(){
    return $this->role;

}
public function getPassword(){
    return $this->password;
}
public function getSalt(){
    return null;
}
public function getUsername(){
    return $this->email;
}
public function eraseCredentials(){
}   
public function isEqualTo(UserInterface $user)
{
    if (!$user instanceof CustomUsers) {
        return false;
    }

    if ($this->user_password !== $user->getPassword()) {
        return false;
    }

    //if ($this->salt !== $user->getSalt()) {
    //    return false;
    //}

    if ($this->email !== $user->getUsername()) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
}
?>
```

That's it, you still have some work to figure it all out by yourself but I hope that will give you directions that I had a really hard time to find on **HOW TO USE SYMFONY WITHOUT ORM**:))